# How to delete rows based on filtering criterion of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to keep only those rows that have the first non-NaN value equal to `AD` and at least two subsequent values that are not equal to `NaN` neither to `AD`.

For example, in this dataframe I would need to delete the third row, because it only has `MM` after `AD`, while rows 2 and 3 have two or more values. I would need also to delete the forth row because it does not start from `AD`:

```
MD_1   MD_2   MD_3    MD_4   MD_5
NaN    AD     VV      DD     NaN
AD     MM     VV      NaN    NaN 
AD     MM     NaN     NaN    NaN
TT     AD     MM      NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = ...

def checker(x):
    row = x.dropna()
    if (row[0] == 'AD') and (('AD' not in row[1:]) and (len(row[1:]) >= 2)):
        return x

    return np.nan

print(df.apply(checker, axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=0))

  MD_1 MD_2 MD_3 MD_4  MD_5
0  NaN   AD   VV   DD   NaN
1   AD   MM   VV  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `&`? And this will crash if row is all Nan.

Comment: @XinHuang Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `row[0] == 'AG')`? Does it assume that the analysis should always start from the column 0?

Comment: I get a strange result like `175       [None, None, None, None, None, None`

Comment: @Dinosaurius Hmm, it works for me with your example. Please try `print(df.dropna(how='all', axis=0).apply(checker, axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=0))` which drops np.nan-row first. Or could you show me your full data?

Answer (score 0):

This will handle all the conditions

```
df = df[((df['MD_1'].isnull()) | (df['MD_1'] == 'AD')) & 
    ((df['MD_2'].notnull()) & (df['MD_2'] != 'AD')) & 
    ((df['MD_3'].notnull()) & (df['MD_3'] != 'AD')) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am searching for a more flexible solution. What happens if I have 100 columns `MD*`?

Comment: If you have more than 100 columns then its definitely a different scale of a problem and can not be handled by what if I have more than 100 columns.